# NSDate from NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am testing some dateFormatter and i have a problem with a simple

```
formatter :

- (void)testDate {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
    NSString *stringDate = @"23/03/1";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
    XCTAssertTrue(date == nil);
}
```

My tests is red because the date is not nil. When i print the date :

```
(lldb) po date
0001-03-22 23:50:39 +0000
```

The NSDateFormatter is padding the date string ( 1 ----> 0001).I don't want this padding. Do you think that it's the correct behaviour of the NSDateFormatter ? ( is it a bug in the NSDateFormatter class ? ). How i can avoid this ?

Thanks

Comment: (See: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)
)

Comment: I have read it and don't see any error in my code, do you see anything ?

Comment: Is your question why `dd/MM/yyyy` successfully parsed `23/3/1`? Or is your question why, after successfully parsing it, the `po date` showed the year as four digit number with zero padding? FYI, the padding of the `po date` output has nothing to do with `NSDateFormatter`, but rather with the `description` method which `po` employs for outputting strings.

Comment: My question si the first : Why it parses it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good answer to why is `@"23/03/1"` considered a valid date with a formatter of `@"dd/MM/yyyy"`. That's just how it works. But if you want to test to see if it's in `##/##/####` format, you could do:

```
NSRange range = [stringDate rangeOfString:@"^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
XCTAssert(range.location == NSNotFound, @"Not in ##/##/#### format");
```

Clearly, you'll have to combine that with the `NSDateFormatter` test to make sure that the values are reasonable, too, but the above will test the number of digits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i will submit it as a bug report and see what Apple engineers thinks about it.

Comment: @samir - It will be interesting what they say, but I won't be surprised if they glibly reply "works as designed" because changing/fixing it would break backward compatibility, a sacrosanct feature of any API. I don't think many people rely on the behavior for `yyyy` but I bet there is a ton of code that does rely upon `MM` and `dd` matching single digits, and this behavior you describe is just the `yyyy` equivalent. Maybe we'll eventually see a new `formatterBehavior` setting.

Answer (score 0):

The date formatter is only being used for parsing the string date to an `NSDate`.

The lldb `po` command just formats the date based on what some Apple developer thought would be good and it **just for debugging**. Internally `NSDate` uses a proprietary format we believe to be the number of seconds since the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

What you want is to use the date formatter to format the date into the string format you want.

Example code using the format string in the question code:

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
```

Output:

> dateString: 23/03/1999

Add an output date format to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is Why is @"23/03/1" is a valid date when converting it with the NSDateFormatter ? ( i have specifier in my formatter that the year should be in 4 digits )

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that as "dd/MM/yyyy" is just a format, when `NSDateFormatter` processes it, parses given date as 3 numbers and makes transition to date. So "1" is just transferred to "0001".